Camera jump in quaternion rotation with mouse input


I'm writing a small 3d engine and there is a problem with a “free” camera. I rotate the camera with a quaternion, and expect that when scrolling the mouse wheel the camera will move in the direction of the view, and when dragging we will rotate the scene relative to the camera position.
As a result, I see the camera shifting to one point (as in the second photo) and the cube rotating in the corner of the screen. What am I doing wrong? Please suggest the source of the problem and a possible solution.
Full project code: https://github.com/LeonidPreis/engine
export class Camera {
    constructor(canvas, target, position, near, far, fovY) {
        this.canvas = canvas;
        this.target = target;
        this.position = position;
        this.near = near;
        this.far = far;
        this.fovY = fovY * Math.PI / 180;
        this.forward = Vector.subtract(this.target, this.position).normalize();
        this.right = Vector.cross(new Vector([0, 1, 0, 1]), this.forward).normalize();
        this.up = Vector.cross(this.forward, this.right);
        this.radius = Vector.subtract(this.position, this.target).length();
        this.rotation = new Quaternion([1,0,0,0])
        this.lastMouseX = 0;
        this.lastMouseY = 0;
        this.isRotating = true;
        this.canvas.canvas.addEventListener('wheel', this.handleScroll.bind(this), false);
        this.canvas.canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', this.startRotation.bind(this), false);
    }
    handleScroll(event) {
        const delta = event.deltaY;
        const increment = delta < 0 ? 1.1 : 0.9;
        this.radius *= increment;
        this.updateCameraPosition();
        Render.main();
    }
    startRotation(event) {
        this.lastMouseX = event.clientX;
        this.lastMouseY = event.clientY;
        this.isRotating = true;
        const onMouseMove = this.rotateCamera.bind(this);
        const onMouseUp = () => {
            this.isRotating = false;
            this.canvas.canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
            this.canvas.canvas.removeEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);
        };
        this.canvas.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove, false);
        this.canvas.canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp, false);
    }
    rotateCamera(event) {
        if (!this.isRotating)
            return;
        const deltaX = event.clientX - this.lastMouseX;
        const deltaY = event.clientY - this.lastMouseY;
        const rotateSpeed = 0.005;
        const qYaw = Quaternion.from.angleAxis(-deltaX, new Vector([0,1,0]));
        const qPitch = Quaternion.from.angleAxis(-deltaY, new Vector([1,0,0]));
        this.rotation = Quaternion.multiply.quaternion(
            Quaternion.multiply.quaternion(qYaw,qPitch),
            this.rotation
        ).normalize()
        this.updateCameraPosition();
        this.lastMouseX = event.clientX;
        this.lastMouseY = event.clientY;
        Render.main();
    }
    updateCameraPosition() {
        this.forward = Quaternion.multiply.vector(
            this.rotation, new Vector([0,0,-1])
        ).normalize();
        this.right = Quaternion.multiply.vector(
            this.rotation, new Vector([1,0,0])
        ).normalize();
        this.up = Vector.cross(this.forward, this.right).normalize();
        this.position = Vector.add(this.target, Vector.multiply.scalar(this.forward, -this.radius));
        this.target = Vector.add(this.position, Vector.multiply.scalar(this.forward, this.radius));
    }
}

